# SQL MAX() Function Not Working As Expected

Tags: sql, join, group-by, max, greatest-n-per-group

I am attempting to select the max `requester_req` for each `customer` group, but after trying numerous different approaches, my result set continues to display every row instead of the max for the customer group.

#### The query:

```
SELECT 
x2.customer, 
x.customer_req, 
x2.requester_name, 
MAX(x2.requester_req) AS requester_req

FROM x, x2

WHERE x.customer = x2.customer

GROUP BY x2.customer, x2.requester_name, x.customer_req

ORDER BY x2.customer
```

#### A sample result set:

```
customer          customer_req          requester_name          requester_req
Bob's Burgers     7                     Bob                     9
Bob's Burgers     7                     Jon                     12
Hello Kitty       9                     Jane                    3
Hello Kitty       9                     Luke                    7
```

#### Expected result set:

```
customer          customer_req          requester_name          requester_req
Bob's Burgers     7                     Jon                     12
Hello Kitty       9                     Luke                    7
```

Have I screwed up something in my group by clause? I can't count how many times I've switched things up and get the same result set.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Please use modern join syntax, available since SQL-92, that is 27 years ago.

Comment: Yes: your group-by clause says to produce one row per unique combination of (customer, requester_name, customer_req).  You can see in the result set that the request_name field is different on each row.   Your desired result is just one row per customer.  You can remove requester_name and customer_req from the group-by and either add an aggregate function in the select, or remove them from the select as well.

Comment: Explain why you expect that. Otherwise we can only guess at your misconception(s). PS Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> select the max requester_req for each customer group

Don't aggregate. Instead, you can filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select 
    x2.customer, 
    x.customer_req, 
    x2.requester_name, 
    x2.requester_req
from x
inner join x2 on x.customer = x2.customer
where x2.requester_req = (
    select max(x20.requester_req) from x2 x20 where x20.customer = x2.customer
)
order by x2.customer
```

Side note: always use explicit, standard joins (with the `on` keywords) instead of old-school implicit joins (with commas in the `from` clause): this syntax is not recommended anymore since more than 20 years, mostly because it is harder to follow.

Comment: You are a lifesaver. I can't believe I didn't think of this... doh. Will accept this answer once the 10-minute timer is up. :) Thank you again!